# How to make TabActivity call onActivityResult? (EDITED TITLE)

Tags: android, android-activity

For some reason when I ask for 1D bar code scan the method onActivityResult isn't called. Is there a workaround to this? If not, is there another barcode app I can integrate with my App or will I need to build one from scratch?

Code:

```
btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {   
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
            intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "PRODUCT_MODE");

            try{
                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex){
                showDownloadDialog();
            }
        }
    });
```

Return code:

```
    @Override public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent){
    if (requestCode == 0)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Scan");
        builder.setMessage(intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT"));

        builder.create().show();

        Log.d("SCAN", "sup");
    }

    Log.d("SCAN", "sup sup");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Actually, not even QR Code is calling onActivityResult. I am using TabActivity. Maybe this has to do with something?

EDIT 2: Ok, I tried using startActivity on ActivityB. ActivityB was responsible for calling startActivityForResult(zxing) and then in the onActivityResult emit an log. Worked. Now I just need to know what is the problem with TabActivity.

Comment: Try a positive integer for your request code i.e. 123

Comment: The Intent extra key is just "SCAN_MODE", not the long string you have constructed here.

Comment: @Blundell I tried, nothing =[

Comment: @SeanOwen I tried "SCAN_CODE", but wasn't working. So I specified the full package and the app loaded. I found this solution in another question. I tried using a ghost activity and worked with PRODUCT_MODE and QR_CODE_MODE. So the problem isn't with ZXing, and yes with TabActivity.

Comment: What that means is that you had previously selected a different application as the default handler for the intent. It was getting chosen to handle it, and receiving the callback, as a result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to have onActivityResult called. On the child activity, I used:

`getParent().startActivityForResult(intent, positive_request_code);`

Then, in the parent activity (TabActivity), I put my onActivityResult there.